# First Isomorphism Theorem, quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be group; let H and K be subgroups of G, with a normal subgroup of G. Prove every member of the quotient group HK/H may be written in the form Hk for some k in K. Not sure what to even do with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of G then $gH=Hg\quad \forall g \in G$

The quotient group of $HK/H$ is defined as {$hkH $ | $hk \in HK$}  but as H is a normal subgroup  this is equal to {$Hhk $ | $hk \in HK$} and $Hh$ = $H$ as H is a subgroup and therefore closed under multiplication as $h \in H$